# Feeding TeamCity coverage runner report to SonarQube runner

Tags: sonarqube, teamcity, code-coverage

My build configuration has 2 steps:

1. Gradle build with Coverage runner set to IntelliJ IDEA
2. SonarQube runner

I am thinking of using the coverage report generated by the coverage runner to put in SonarQube runner in the second step. Can I check where the report is stored on the build agent directory? ( I have no access to teamCity build agent as they are managed by other team in my company)

Similarly for Jacoco Coverage runner, where is the report to feed into SonarQube parameter -Dsonar.jacoco.reportPaths ?

I am using TeamCity 10.0.5